# is there a way to undo a created lookup table in oracle apex?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-apex

I have created a lookup table for an existing table and now I want to undo what I did and bring the original table to its original form.
I, unfortunately, don't know how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a lookup table generates a table and a sequence. The format is <column_name>_LOOKUP (for the table) and <column_name>_LOOKUP_SEQ (for the sequence).
They can both be dropped in the object browser.

Comment: i cannot drop the lookup tale as it is still connected to the table.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to drop the lookup table and make the data look the same as before in the original table?
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: ah - in my test there were no data updates. Dan explains in this post what happens when you create a lookup table: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61247718/oracle-apex-lookup-table-with-several-links. I suggest you check that and reverse - engineer